# How to unlock folder in delphi

Tags: delphi

i had created two service,both are using same folder..i want to unlocked the folder when first service work got over..plz help?????

Comment: Urget = please close my question.

Comment: Folders don't get locked, files do. Why exactly are you concerned about the "locking"? What are you trying to do, and what exactly is happening?

Comment: His urgent request has gone without feedback from him for 24 minutes. Turns out it wasn't urgent after all.

Answer (score 2):

Its not clear what you want. But two or more processes can use the same folder.

You can't delete or rename a folder that is in use by another process.

If you read and write a file at the same time, results can be unpredictable. But if you open a file you can specify if you want exclusive access.

Comment: i have to process one is 'orderUploderservice'.its upload the particular folder.once its done then other process which also listen same folder to delete that folder after orderUploderService..Once one folder uploaded by orderUploderService then orderUploderService listen to other folder...but my problem is that its remains holding the previous folder also..so i am not able to delete previous folder..is there ant method to unlock the folder after orderUploderService is done for that folder.

Comment: @Prakash - your orderUploderService obviously hasn't released all references to the file it uploaded, which is keeping the file locked, and because the file is locked you cannot delete the folder. We can't tell you how to fix it unless you give more details - a code sample would be best.

Comment: procedure TOrderUploader.ProcessOrder(OrderDir: TFileSystemString; MarkerFile: TFileSystemString);
  var
    ProgressMarkerFile, SuccessMarkerFile, FailureMarkerFile: TFileSystemString;
    LoginID: String;
  begin
    try
      ProgressMarkerFile := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(OrderDir) + FProgressMarkerFileName;
      RenameFile(MarkerFile, ProgressMarkerFile);
      CreateOnlineOrder(OrderDir);
      SuccessMarkerFile := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(OrderDir) + FSuccessMarkerFileName;
      RenameFile(ProgressMarkerFile, SuccessMarkerFile);

Comment: EmailClient.SendEmail(FEmailFrom, FEmailTo, Format(FSuccessEmailSubject, [LoginID]), '', 'text/plain');
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        FailureMarkerFile := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(OrderDir) + FFailureMarkerFileName;
        RenameFile(ProgressMarkerFile, FailureMarkerFile);
        LoginID := GetLoginID(OrderDir);
        EmailClient.SendEmail(FEmailFrom, FEmailTo, Format(FFailureEmailSubject, [LoginID]), E.Message, 'text/plain');

Comment: procedure TOrderCleaner.ProcessOrder(OrderDir: TFileSystemString; MarkerFile: TFileSystemString);
  begin
    try
      Log.Info(Format('Deleting order dir %s...', [OrderDir]));
      DeleteDir(OrderDir);
      Log.Info('Done');
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        Log.Error(Format('Failed to delete order dir %s.', [OrderDir]), E);
      end;
    end;
  end;

Comment: now i think u clear about my question

Comment: @Prakash: you should update your answer instead of posting code in comments. Maybe your question will get reopened.